# Sitecore ECM Engagement plan Custom action in "Message Opened" state

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms, sitecore-ecm

I need to update few information regarding the visitor when a visitor is in `Message Opened` state of Sitecore ECM standard engagement plan.

Therefore I need to create a custom action or something where I can push in my custom code to do the visitor data manipulation.

I tried doing it via creating a script and attaching it to a trigger and finally attaching the trigger to the state. but no luck unfortunately.

Is this task even possible or am I missing something ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Message Opened` state is forbidden to change. It is a kind of a system ECM state. You can customize only states of the **green** area (Productive, Unproductive, etc.).

However there is a way to do what you want.
The moment of message open is handled with the help of small image added at the bottom of a mail. Image source is an ASPX page. When a recipient downloads mail images, the ASPX page is requested.
You can customize the ASPX page requested by the image (add your code there).

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks so much for the reply. Can you please also post what ASPX page it requests ? - Thanks

Comment: I do not remember its name and location. Try to send an HTML message to yourself and analyze its body.